# Are designation of voltage current quantities with upper and lower case letters universal

Tags: voltage, current

Below shows designation of voltage current quantities with upper lower case letters:

[image]

RMS value for instance is indicated with upper case letter with small subscript.

Is this above table universally accepted? Is there a standard?

Comment: Generally speaking - no. In Russian technical literature for example they use Russian letters for electrical (and other engineering) quantities. But there are *common* designations.

Comment: Im asking standardization in being capital or lower case and subscripts, not the letter itself is Chinese or Russian.

Comment: Not all languages (you mentioned Chinese?) have capitalization at all.

Comment: Then it means they use latin letters for electrical eng

Comment: look at their wiki https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/平方平均数

Comment: This is just one example. As I said, they can use whatever they decide. If you want to narrow it down, ask about English/Latin notation only. But the answer will be "no" as well. As I said - there are commonly accepted notations(and they are application specific mostly), but they are not carved in stone, and that is why in every technical paper you will find a table with the terms definition.

Comment: Most text books are consistent and some have tables like the one you show indicating what convention is being used. That is about the limit of consistency. It is almost universal that V is used for voltage and I for current, but sometimes E is used for voltage (electromotive force). Vcc is commonly used. The use of upper and lower case is completely arbitrary. You may get some more opinions, but my opinion is that there can be no definite answer.

Comment: Another vote for "no standard". Some of my textbooks used capital letters for either AC _or_ DC. Unless they were both present, then DC was capitalized (\$V_1\$ , \$I_1\$) and AC was lower-case (\$v_1\$ , \$i_1\$).  In other textbooks, large-signal stuff was always capitalized (AC or DC) and the small-signal components were lower-case.

Comment: Usually capital letters are used for amplitude or DC values (Vdc, Vmax,..), small letters are for dynamically changing values or AC, like u=u(t), i=i(t),...signals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The designation of voltages and currents as shown in the picture you added were part of the old IEC 148 (or IEC 60148:1963) standard, which was superseded by IEC 60748-1:1984 in 1984 (current revision is 2002): these recommendations are now probably part of this last standard. I saw them for the first time long ago, in the "General" section of a Philips Transmitting Tubes Manual: below I have added few scans from a more (but not so much...) recent Philips manual.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can also refer to IEC 60050 (https://www.electropedia.org/) which is available online for the correct symbols and terms.

$$U \text{ and } u(t)$$

are better symbols to use for voltage.

Comment: "Electropedia" is not a recognized standard. If you say that \$U\$ is preferred you better have a citation to a recognized international standard. IEEE Std 280 lists \$V\$ and \$E\$ as preferred symbols for voltage, with \$U\$ to be used only when necessary to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Electropedia is the web interface to IEC 60050.  Granted it is not an ISO document, only and European standard as IEEE is also only an American standard.

Comment: OK,  then cite a section of IEC 60050 rather than just a url.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Done.